# Asp dotnet core how to connect email

Tags: office365api

My application will be hosted in Linux. Console application intranet application.
I need to read email from office 365 . can you please suggest how this can be achieved. i tried exchange service but Auto discover issue restricted by client. 
Some way to connect email and read attachment

Comment: i am able to connect office 365 email in windows using Microsoft.Exchange.Service .But when i deployed in Linux ,its not able to resolve Auto discovery URL and error i am finding "dnsapi dll " not found.

Comment: I will be deploying in Linux, will it be working if I use azure register? Can you clarify please

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/overview) is the way to go here. The [Graph SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph) works in .NET Core, here's a [sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-connect-sample).

Comment: Hi Jason Will Microsoft graph will work in Apache Linux?